# Is there any way to extract transactions in uncles?

Tags: uncle-blocks

As stated in the [wiki](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_getunclebyblocknumberandindex):

> Note: An uncle doesn't contain individual transactions.

I would still like to extract transactions from uncle blocks. Is there any method available for doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uncle are blocks that are not longert part of the main chain due to a chain reorganization. You can try calling `getBlock(hash)` if it was mined recently.

Nodes will stop propagating once it was mined as an uncle. Even archival nodes might not have the data anymore if they started to sync after the block was mined.

Comment: Correct, I am using Infura as a service and they have the data available!